# RailsTutorial: Section 8.2.5, isn't it possible to avoid code duplication with is_logged_in? method

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm yet another newbie performing Rails Tutorial (3rd edition) from Michael Hartl.

In section 8.2.5, to perform some test, he recommands to write a test helper method nammed **is_logged_in?** and to use it in some integration test (**UsersSignupTest**).

Previously, a very similar helper method have been created: **logged_in?** part of the **controllers/helpers/sessions_helper**.

I am concerned by the code duplication I see between these 2 methods.

I assume that Hartl refuse to perform an include of the sessions helper method in the test code for a good reason (and perhaps obvious) but I have not been able to find it by my own.

Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried including the helper from /controllers/helpers in your test suite?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the `SessionsHelper#logged_in?` method is not available for use in the `UsersSignupTest` but we still need to test whether the user is logged in after a signup with valid information.

So instead of writing `assert !session[:user_id].nil?`, which would've worked too (after all, the session is available for use in the tests), the author instead decided to parallel the `SessionsHelper#logged_in?` method in a helper for tests.
I suppose it helps with the readability of the `UsersSignupTest` integration test.

Yes, there's a  bit of duplication going on here (even that is debatable), but as the author explains, it seems helpful in this context.